# FastApi - receive list of objects in body request

Tags: python, json, fastapi, pydantic

I need to create an endpoint that can receive the following JSON and recognize the objects contained in it:

```
{​
  "data": [
    {​
      "start": "A", "end": "B", "distance": 6
    }​,
    {​
      "start": "A", "end": "E", "distance": 4
    }​
  ]
}
```

I created a model to handle a single object:

```
class GraphBase(BaseModel):
    start: str
    end: str
    distance: int
```

And with it, I could save it in a database. But now I need to receive a list of objects and save them all.
I tried to do something like this:

```
class GraphList(BaseModel):
    data: Dict[str, List[GraphBase]]

@app.post("/dummypath")
async def get_body(data: schemas.GraphList):
    return data
```

But I keep getting this error on FastApi: `Error getting request body: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)` and this message on the response:

```
{
    "detail": "There was an error parsing the body"
}
```

I'm new to python and even newer to FastApi, how can I transform that JSON to a list of `GraphBase`to save them in my db?

Comment: What about `data: List[GraphBase]` in the definition of `GraphList`? `data` field is a list of graphbase objects.

Comment: @KotaMori I tried your suggestion and it returns the same error.

Comment: Did you try the API on the docs page?

Comment: @KotaMori I tried everything I could find on the API docs page but with no success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a working example.

```py
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

class GraphBase(BaseModel):
    start: str
    end: str
    distance: int

class GraphList(BaseModel):
    data: List[GraphBase]

@app.post("/dummypath")
async def get_body(data: GraphList):
    return data
```

I could try this API on the autogenerated docs.

[image]

Or, on the console (you may need to adjust the URL depending on your setting):

```sh
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8000/dummypath' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "data": [
    {
      "start": "string",
      "end": "string",
      "distance": 0
    }
  ]
}'
```

The error looks like the data problem. And I found that you have extra spaces at several places.  Try the following:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "start": "A", "end": "B", "distance": 6
    },
    {
      "start": "A", "end": "E", "distance": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

The positions of extra spaces (which I removed) are below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I spent a lot of time looking for a problem in the code that was in the data!! It worked with your formatted data. What did you use to locate those extra whitespaces? And do you know if FastApi has a way to handle this kind of problem?

Comment: I used https://jsoneditoronline.org/.  The original data was invalid there.  FastAPI won't help you because the data was not a valid JSON object.  The best it could do is to tell you that the parsing data failed, which actually was in the error message.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that something could be wrong with the data, but couldn't figure out what it was. All editors I used were unable to show those extra spaces and the error message was unclear of what was the issue. Again, thank you for the explanation and the link to the json validator you used!!!

Comment: whilst that will work with json content type , it wont work with formdata content type

Comment: thanks! how do we specify minimum and maximum (or fixed) length of the list expected, for validation?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, FastAPI allows for simply receiving a list of objects, there's no need to wrap that list in an extra object.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class ObjectListItem(BaseModel):
  ...

@app.post("/api_route")
def receive_list_of_objects(objects_list: list[ObjectListItem]):
  ...
```

More information in the [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-nested-models/#bodies-of-pure-lists).

Comment: Assuming I need to post something really simple, like a list of integers, would the `objects_list` passed via the post request  simply be a JSON list : [1,2,3] ?

Comment: There's an example of handling lists of primitive values (e.g. int, str) here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values

To pass it in the request body, you need to declare a Pydantic model for it: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/